# refresh css animation multiple times

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I have this really complex animation that runs once and I can not use "animation-iteration-count: infinite;" to reiterate it multiple times. Is there another way to do this? For example refreshing the div will refresh the animation? (how do you refresh a div?)

this is the html:

```
<div id="hold">
<p id="myname" class="small-caps">
<span id="layer0Go" class="drag">w</span>
<span id="layer1Go" class="drag">w</span>
<span id="layer2Go" class="drag">w</span>
<span id="layer3Go" class="drag">m</span>
<span id="layer4Go" class="drag">e</span>
<span id="layer5Go" class="drag">s</span>
<span id="layer6Go" class="drag">s</span>
<span id="layer7Go" class="drag">a</span>
<span id="layer8Go" class="drag">g</span>
<span id="layer9Go" class="drag">e</span>
<span id="layer10Go" class="drag">l</span>
<span id="layer11Go" class="drag">a</span>
<span id="layer12Go" class="drag">b</span>
<span id="layer13Go" class="drag">r</span>
<span id="layer14Go" class="drag">o</span>
<span id="layer15Go" class="drag ball"></span>
</p>
</div>
```

some of the css:

```
#layer0Go{ -webkit-animation: a0-translate 5s linear 0s 1 none, b0-translate 5s linear 5s 1 none, c0-translate 1.5s linear 10s 1 none, d0-translate 5s linear 11.5s 1 none, v0-translate 7s linear 16.5s 1 forwards;
```

The same css for all layers.

If I put animation-iteration-count: infinite; to #hold it does nothing. Of course if I put it to layer0Go it will repeat the first animation infinitely without running the other animations. 
They are some animated letters changed from this project here: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/demos/detail/css-tricks
Any ideas?
I made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2AnEJ/

Comment: Better question, why in the world would you want to do any of this ??

Comment: :)) the animation is really nice, but it is down on the page and the user can't see it unless he scrolls down, so by the time he arrives there the animation will be finished... (it is for the smaller screen version site so I have no space to put it up)

Comment: If you have a jsFiddle it'd probably be the only way someone could help :/

Comment: Of course! Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2AnEJ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To refresh the div simply do this...

```
$("#animatie").html($("#animatie").html());
```

You could use setInterval to reset it after each batch of animation is done.

http://jsfiddle.net/2AnEJ/1/

(obviously that's an example - change the interval to the total time of the animations)